# Удаление оповещений от просматриваемых проектов в GitHub

Tags: github

Добрый день. Если отметить любой репозиторий как просматриваемый в GitHub, то на главной странице github.com отображаются изменения и ссылки на коммиты, которые произошли в этих (просматриваемых) репозиториях. Если же убрать отметку "просматриваемый" с репозитория, то все новости и изменения с главной страницы не пропадают. Каким образом убрать все ненужные новости и все уже пришедшие нотификации?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/notifications?all=1

Обратите внимание на кнопку <kbd>Mark all as read</kbd> в верхнем правом углу. Вам нужна именно она.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я раньше это не отыскал. Но странно, что она мне не помогла. У меня в данный момент все в точности так же, как и у Вас. То есть в списке All notifications пусто. При этом нотификации на главной странице никуда не пропали.  

http://imglink.ru/show-image.php?id=f4486ec18494b700d6a708297863d1d0   

http://imglink.ru/show-image.php?id=f8e55d7d637a73ae4508c5bb8226f530

Comment: @KirillBelov может быть, вы всё ещё подписаны на разработчика (т.е. Follow)?

Comment: Да, это я тоже проверил. На пользователя я был подписан, но сейчас нет. Это странно очень. Мне сейас не приходит новых оповещений, но старые отображаются и никуда не пропадают.